# UILabel's layer doesn't update color while animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, catransition

I am animating a `UILabel` to 'evaporate' off the screen using `CATransition`.
I want the label text to turn green, and move off the screen.

The following code does 'evaporate' the label fine, but doesn't change its colour before animating:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
transition.duration = 0.4;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;

[self.displayLabel.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"evaporate"];

self.displayLabel.textColor = [self greenColor];
self.displayLabel.text = @" ";
```

Calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the label doesn't work.
Can't use a `CABasicAnimation` because the label text is changing.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: let us see what the docs says, after a minute research: _"The following properties of the `UIView` class are animatable: `frame`, `bound`, `center`, `transform`, `alpha`, `backgroundColor`, `contentStretch`"_... maybe that is why you cannot animate the `textColor`, perhaps?

Comment: @holex We are talking about using CoreAnimation here, not UIView based animations. AFAIK, CoreAnimation is content agnostic. I just want CA to animate the label *after* the textColor changes and the layer is updated. The docs also say that the `contents` property of a `CALayer` is animatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want nested animations or, in a sense, looking for a completion block type thing.
The closest I can think of achieving this is by using the `CATransition` delegate

### Example:

```
-(IBAction)btnTest:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //[1] Animate text color change

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self]; //important
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES]; //better to remove the animation
    [animation setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime()]; //not really needed
    [animation setDuration:0.4];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];

    //you can specify any key name or keep it nil. doesn't make a difference
    [self.displayLabel.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeTextColor"];
    [self.displayLabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

---

```
#pragma mark - CATransition Delegate
-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    //[2] Animate text sublayer

    /*
     The following CATransition should not set a delegate
     otherwise this animation will loop continously
    */

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:YES]; //better to remove the animation
    [animation setBeginTime:CACurrentMediaTime()]; //not really needed
    [animation setDuration:0.4];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault]];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];

    //you can specify any key name or keep it nil. doesn't make a difference
    [self.displayLabel.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"changeText"];
    [self.displayLabel setText:@" "];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this tonight and report back.

Comment: @duci9y : sure. well... there is no specific 'evaporate' type animation but I think this is what you're basically going for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though couldn't exactly get the effect I was looking for, this works for now.

Comment: @duci9y : you're welcome. btw... the effect you want, is it to have the text turn green **while** moving up?

Comment: Nope, turn green, and then move up.

Comment: @duci9y : great. so basically, this was a simple way to do that. just not very 'evaporate' like

Comment: Managed to get an evaporate like thing with a fade+push. ;)